# Refresh current email item view after the updating it by the Outlook REST API

Tags: office-js, outlook-restapi, outlook-web-addins

Office-js: 16.0.11215.10000
Outlook for Mac: 16.22
OS: MacOS High Sierra

I'm updating the current outlook email item with this REST API request:

```
let restItemId = Office.context.mailbox.convertToRestId(Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId, Office.MailboxEnums.RestVersion.v2_0);    
$http({
  method: 'PATCH',
  url: 'https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/' + restItemId,
  headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
  data: {
    Body: {
        ContentType: 'HTML',
        Content: html_content
    }}
}).then(...);
```

The problem is that in the Outlook web browser client the item content is updated only after the full page refresh. In Outlook desktop client it is updated after moving to different folder and returning back.

Is there a way to refresh the current item content, to reload the current item or, to refresh the outlook by REST API?

Comment: As you observed, the REST call modifies the item on the server directly. There's no way to force the client (Outlook desktop/OWA) from the add-ins. Could you tell us more on you scenario and what you are updating with the REST call? A addins JS API would generally be more appropriate in these cases where the change should be reflected in the client.

Comment: Hi. I want to change the email body content. In gmail I can simply change local html. In outlook as far as I see it's impossible. May be add-in can reload the email item or refresh the whole message view?

Comment: Have you tried using Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook_1_5/office.body?view=office-js#setasync-data--options--callback- ?

Comment: It doesn't work in read message view.

Comment: Currently modifying the read message body, or refreshing the item in the view, is not a part of the product (either by REST or by office.JS API). We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins